# Term for Doing Something Inmoral and Unethical When Deserving a Handicap

Tags: meaning, loanwords

Is there a term for doing the unmoral and unethical thing when you believe you deserve a handicap?

Paul used a reading prompt against the rules because he had a speed and memory impediment.

Comment: **Taking the moral high ground** may apply, as this usually has a connotation of you acting morally while others don't.

Comment: **Turning the other cheek** has a similar meaning with a biblical origin.

Comment: **Going against the current** or *swimming upstream*?

Comment: @JohnClifford what if it is a victim less crime and nobody else has the choice?

Comment: Can you write an example sentence where the term would be used? The following is the strict rule of this community. *Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered*. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). Please edit your question accordingly.